# Ractive condition doesn't work for Hangout Button

Tags: ractivejs, google-hangouts

I have a template that works with HangoutButton:

```
    <div id="templateContainer" class="row">
        <script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
            {{#if HangoutUrl === null}}
            <g:hangout render="createhangout">
            </g:hangout>
            {{else}}
            <a id="hangoutUrl" href="{{HangoutUrl}}" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Hangout</a>
            {{/if}}
        </script>
    </div>
```

If HangoutUrl is not specified I display a Hangout button, in other case I display a usual anchor. If I load the page when HangoutUrl is not specified yet and then I set the HangoutUrl value (without page reloading) here is what I see:

[image]

So instead of displaying just the anchor I get both of them. I guess it is caused by the ugly html that Hangout button generates.

What can I do to make Hangout button removed in case HangoutUrl is specified?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by wrapping Hangout Button with div:

```
{{#if HangoutUrl === null}}
     <div>
            <g:hangout render="createhangout" lang="en-US" initial_apps="[{ app_id : '115733298764', start_data : '@Model.Id', 'app_type' : 'LOCAL_APP' }]">
            </g:hangout>
     </div>
{{else}}
```

I'm still not sure why it works this way. May be it is a bug in Ractive?

Comment: What version of Ractive? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/bnpe6mwh/1/) appears to work.